# Proving that a set of polynomials with a common root is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set of $n$ polynomials $p_i(x)$ of degree at most $n$ all having roots at $2$, prove that they are linearly dependent.

I would go like: $a_1p(2)+a_2p(2)+...+a_np(n)=0$. So then the $a_i$ need not all be 0. I feel this is incorrect. If this is correct I don't understand why.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the problem statement: $p_1(x) = x-2$ and  $p_2(x) = (x-2)^2$ are linearly *independent* ...

Comment: I puzzled a bit over the "asset" of a polynomial then realized it was "a set"!  A set of polynomials (functions in general), {$p_1$, $p_2$, …, $p_n$}, is "independent" if and only if the polynomial $a_1p_1+ a_2p_2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ a_np_n$ is **identically 0" (0 for **all** x) only if all coefficients are 0.  Being 0 at one value of x is not sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need $n+1$ polynomials for this to be true.

Let $q_i(x)=\frac {p_i(x)} {x-2}$. Then $q_i$'s are polynomials of degree at most $n-1$ and there are $n+1$ of them. Hence some non-trivial linear combination of them  vanishes. Just multiply by $x-2$ to finish the proof.

There are easy examples (like the one provided by Martin R) to show that the result is false  as stated.

Comment: @JeanMarie I meant to say most $n-1$ for the degree of $q_i$'s. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials of degree at most $n$. Then $V$ has dimension $n+1$.

The map $f \mapsto f(2)$ is a surjective linear map $V \to \mathbb R$. Therefore, its kernel has dimension $(n+1)-1=n$.

Thus, any $n+1$ polynomials having $2$ as a root are linearly independent.

Comment: cool explaination!